# Using a single repository to share private cocoapods

Tags: git, cocoapods

I currently have a git repository with a CocoaPods folder containing a .framework (with git tags for each version) that I would like to share as a private pod.

So I created a podspec file at the same level as the CocoaPods folder and I added this file into that git repository. But now when I update the repo, the "CocoaPods" folder is added into the ~/.cocoapods/repos/MY_REPO/ folder. 
Since it is my first CocoaPod usage, I can't know if it is the intended behavior, but when I run "pod repo lint MY_REPO" the files in this folder makes the validation fail.

So should I use a separate git repo to store the podspec file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pod "MyPod", :path => "."` to use Pods in the same folder as your Podfile, there's no need to create an entire Podspec repo ( like [Artsy's](https://github.com/artsy/specs) ) until it needs to work on multiple projects.

Comment: in my case that pod will be used my multiple developers on different projects, and I will progressively add other .frameworks with that first one, so I would like to mimic Artsy's way. But I won't need a separate git repo for each library, so do I need 2 git repo (1 only hosting .podspec files like the one you linked in your answer and 1 for all the libraries with their tags) or is 1 single repo mixing both ok ? And if 1 is ok, how do I tell "pod repo.." to checkout only the .podspec files from that repo into the ~/.cocoapods/repos/MY_REPO/ folder to avoid lint errors ?

Comment: You'd need the repo just for Podspecs, but all the metadata in the Podspecs can point to the same (other) repo, they can't be the same repo

Comment: so you have 2 git repo in the end? It's hard to understand because you say "the metadata CAN point to the same repo", and just after "they CAN'T be the same repo" oO

Comment: I did say "other" right after that, referring to the repo with code, not Podspecs.

Comment: Why do you say it's the "same" repo, if it is another one ? Sorry to insist but I did not understand your comment at all. Maybe I should have asked if you could rephrase it differently (my English skills are not perfect).

Comment: All your libraries can be in one repo, all your podspecs can be in a different repo. Then your podspecs are in a "podspecs repo" and the metadata inside those podspecs can refer to code inside the libraries repo.